# Qt with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

I've downloaded the source and compiled it from the VS command prompt using nmake.
I've also installed the VS 2010 addin. However, now when I go to **Qt** -> **Options** -> **Add** and find the newly Qt compiled binaries, it says:

"Qt in the given path was compiled with MinGW."

No I haven't. What's this all about? I've used "-platform win32-msvc2010" to configure too.

EDIT:

just to add, the path I was browsing for was like: QTDIR\qt\

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have the binaries from the Qt sdk on the machine and it's finding those instead of the ones you compiled.

Comment: Well, the qmake in QTDIR\qt\bin\ has the creation date of the compilation as do all of the files in that folder, so that has to be the right qmake... I have no other Qt SDK's on my PC.